# PHP - preg_match whole word from associative array, working with stristr but not preg_match

Tags: php, regex, arrays, foreach, preg-match

I am looping through an associative array and trying to match the whole word from the needle array into the haystack array. The following code works perfectly but returns too many results since it's matching any occurance of the string:

```
$result = array();
$name1 = array();
$name2 = array();
foreach($object->organizations as $o) {
    foreach($objectCrunch as $o2) {
        $name1 = $o->name;
        $name2 = $o2->name;

        if(stristr($name2, $name1)) {
            $result[] = $o2->permalink;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try the following code:

```
$result = array();
$name1 = array();
$name2 = array();
foreach($object->organizations as $o) {
    foreach($objectCrunch as $o2) {
        $name1 = $o->name;
        $name2 = $o2->name;

        $pattern = "'/\b" . $name2 . "\b/i'";

        if(preg_match($pattern, $name1)) {
            $result[] = $o2->permalink;
        }
    }
}
```

I get an empty array. Any help getting the last piece of code working would be great.

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: Try replacing `$pattern = "'/\b" . $name2 . "\b/i'";` with `$pattern = "'/\b" . preg_quote( $name2) . "\b/i'";`

Comment: server error... I don't think the $pattern string is the problem. I think the question is whether my regex is correct.

Comment: Your `$pattern` string is forming a regex, so the two are one in the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two pairs of [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) here:

```
$pattern = "'/\b" . $name2 . "\b/i'";
            ||      
            1|
             2
```

Use either `/` or `'`.
I'd say the single quotes are redundant and the result of hasty copy & pasting.

Also, [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote) for the content/word if it might contain either.

---

So as Elias points out; The next pitfall is likely trying to use the long content variable as search parameter. This would have been an obvious error, if you didn't give your variables meaningless enumerated names.

Only one of them is likely an actual word or name. The other should be called content or something:

```
    $word = $o->name;
    $textcontent = $o2->name;
```

Use those henceforth.
While at it, also fix the object property naming accordingly.

Comment: `preg_quote` will also be necessary if `$name2` contains any special regex characters that we don't want to be evaluated, such as a period, asterisk, or plus sign.

Comment: good catch, but isn't the problem even more fundamental then this? ie: haystack -> needle vs pattern -> string

Comment: That was my point, the OP is using the haystack from the `stristr` call as a pattern, to match against the $name1 variable

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly simple, really. Thanks to some quirks in php, `stristr` syntax is as follows:

```
stristr($haystack,$needle);
```

while `preg_match`'s first argument serves as a needle. Example:

```
$name1 = 'name of chief object';
$name2 = 'I am a child of name of chief object';
stristr($name2,$name1);//looks for 'name of chief object' in $name2

preg_match('/\b'.$name2.'\b/i',$name1);//does the exact oposite
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. `$name2` indeed is the haystack, so it won't work as search parameter (in whatever regex variation) to preg_match. -- So, if anything, it's a lesson in how not to give expressionless variable names.